# How to properly create objects instead of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create a object using my placeholder. The current code works however it is creating array in my Children property. How can I recode so that my output is object

```
const placeholder = (index, isRootDirectory) => {
  const create = {
    id: index,
    title: null,
    location: index,
    isRootDirectory,
    padStyle: [
      {
        icon: null,
        color: null,
      },
    ],
    UUID: null,
    action: null,
    Children: [],
  };

  return create;
};

const createLayout = () => {
  let root = {
    info: "Custom Layout",
    Children: [],
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    root.Children.push(placeholder(i, true));
    console.log(root);
  }

  console.log(root);
};
```

Current output:

```
{"Children": [{"Children": [Array], "UUID": null, "action": null, "id": 0, "isRootDirectory": true, "location": 0, "padStyle": [Array], "title": null}, {"Children": [Array], "UUID": null, "action": null, "id": 1, "isRootDirectory": true, "location": 1, "padStyle": [Array], "title": null}], "info": "Custom Layout"}
```

Desired output

```
{"Children": [{"Children": [object], "UUID": null, "action": null, "id": 0, "isRootDirectory": true, "location": 0, "padStyle": [object], "title": null}, {"Children": [object], "UUID": null, "action": null, "id": 1, "isRootDirectory": true, "location": 1, "padStyle": [object], "title": null}], "info": "Custom Layout"}
```

Comment: Is this in Node.js? You seem to be misinterpreting the output. See [How can I get the full object in Node.js's console.log(), rather than '\[Object\]'?](/q/10729276/4642212).

Comment: React Native but I feel that any code in Node would be the same

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you defined the constant `create`, you defined the `Children` key as an array by writing `Children: []`. Instead, write `Children: {}`.
So

```
const create = {
    id: index,
    title: null,
    location: index,
    isRootDirectory,
    padStyle: [
      {
        icon: null,
        color: null,
      },
    ],
    UUID: null,
    action: null,
    Children: [],
  };
```

Would be written as

```
const create = {
    id: index,
    title: null,
    location: index,
    isRootDirectory,
    padStyle: [
      {
        icon: null,
        color: null,
      },
    ],
    UUID: null,
    action: null,
    Children: {},
  };
```